# Getting an error when quotes are passed as an argument in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have an error in my Discord bot currently when someone uses quotes in a command, I get the following error: `discord.ext.commands.errors.ExpectedClosingQuoteError: Expected closing ".` It seems like this is an open bug in `discord.py` according to [this bug report](https://github.com/Cog-Creators/Red-DiscordBot/issues/3055) as well as [this code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/874c2cd3c9ed47fa42eea184b167b8c0c64ea18e/discord/ext/commands/view.py#L30-L48) in `discord.py`. It is a bit annoying that this is the issue and I was wondering if there is any fix for this currently. Here is my code thus far:

```
@bot.command()
async def f(ctx, *args):
hearts = (':heart:', ':orange_heart:', ':yellow_heart:', ':green_heart:', ':blue_heart:', ':purple_heart:')

if not args:
    response = '**{0}** has paid their respects {1}'.format(ctx.author.name,
                                                            hearts[random.randint(0, len(hearts) - 1)])
else:
    response = '**{0}** has paid their respects {1} {2}'.format(ctx.author.name, ' '.join(args),
                                                                hearts[random.randint(0, len(hearts) - 1)])
```

When a user calls this function by typing `!f "The thing` in Discord, I get the command I mentioned above. Is there anyway I can potentially get around this? I don't think it is possible since the minute the argument is passed into the function, the error is thrown. I suppose I can edit `discord.py` to fix this issue, but it might break other areas of my bot. I usually get this error when iOS users use the quotes on their keyboard and type something like `!f Josh's face`. Is there any way to have all quotes be passed successfully through this function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is taking everything after the command as `args` and made the default to None so you would not get an error if there is no args `discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: args is a required argument that is missing.`

also i changed the formatting to use [f string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) i believe it is easier. and using [random.choise()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) is better in your case

[example from docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments)

```py
@bot.command()
async def f(ctx, *, args=None):
    hearts = (':heart:', ':orange_heart:', ':yellow_heart:',
              ':green_heart:', ':blue_heart:', ':purple_heart:')

    if not args:
        response = f'**{ctx.author.name}** has paid their respects {random.choice(hearts)}'
    else:
        response = f'**{ctx.author.name}** has paid their respects {args} {random.choice(hearts)}'

    await ctx.send(response)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for fixing my code and linking the documentation as well. Really helpful! Much appreciated! <3